# Configure Python version per project in SonarQube

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, sonarqube

When analysing a project using the [Python plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Python+Plugin) there are some rules that only apply to Python v3.

**Is it possible to configure (per project) which python version is used** so that only the relevant rules, applicable to that version, are applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. What you want to do is create a [Quality Profile](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles) per Python version, then [assign](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Non-rule+Profile+Edits+and+Information#Non-ruleProfileEditsandInformation-AssigningaProjecttoaQualityProfile) each project to its relevant profile.

In some plugins, language-version-specific tags are applied to show which rules are about features that are new in a particular version of the language. I don't think that work has been done in the Python plugin, but you can sort the rules and add those tags manually if you like.

Comment: Is there a simple way of determining if a particular rule applies to 2.7 and/or 3.x versions?

Comment: See my expansion @Alix